# background image not displaying in IE

Tags: css

I am using a background image for two divs 'user sign up' and 'business sign up' in a div , it is working fine in FF and chrome,but not in IE.you can check the following url http://dev.getchkd.com/signup-a.php

Comment: Not an answer, but you've linked to css/demo.css twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a space character after the `url(...)` and before the `no-repeat`. Since such a syntax error is "kind of recoverable", some browsers will tolerate it.